# Selenium with Chrome is extremely slow if I navigate manually

Tags: python, selenium, performance

I'm creating a small program that logins to my [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/) (a vocabulary-learning app) account, opens tabs on each course, check if I have any remaining vocabulary to review, and if there are, start the session and if not, close the tab.

So far, I made success with the app, but now found that the browser I launched via Selenium is extremely slow once I navigate and tap the word on my own. For example, it takes about 5 second for my typing to be reflected on the screen, which is not true if I type on normal Google Chrome. It is slow even after my program finishes the execution (but the driver is still there to let me review the words). I wonder what makes it too slow and would like to know if there is any way to make it as smooth as when I navigate it on my ordinary Chrome browser.

---

I'm not sure if I can show anything helpful, as everything I wrote is too simple a structure. First create a Selenium driver:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
        "download.default_directory" : download_dir,
        'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'
        }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Then for all the URLs in a list, call     `driver.execute_script('window.open("{0}", "_blank");'.format(url))` to open it in a new tab.

Then, just tab the Review button if there is a review, and close the window if not.

```
remaining_window_handles = driver.window_handles
window_count = len(driver.window_handles)

while window_count > 0:
    driver.switch_to_window(remaining_window_handles[0])
    driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 0);")

    try:
        review_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@data-original-title="Review words you\'ve learned"]'))
        )
        try: # a course with review has the number of reviews in its text
            numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', review_button.text)
            if numbers:
                review_button.click()
            else:
                driver.close()
        except (NoSuchElementException, NoSuchWindowException):
            driver.close()
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.close()

    window_count -= 1
```

I execute it by first launching IPython session, and then run the script. I wonder if the problem comes from the fact that I run it on iTerm2 (M1 MacBook Air), and on Activity Monitor, it seems that normal Chrome is running with `Apple` type yet the Selenium one is with `Intel`.

Comment: In order to help you we need to see and debug your code.

Comment: It's probably the number of tabs.  Chrome is a bit of a resource hog since they fixed some vulnerabilities regarding cross-window security.  (Each tab/window/frame now has it's own separate thread...)

Comment: @pcalkins How many tabs are considered too many? I tried restricting the tabs to 5, but it is still too slow.

Comment: @Prophet Updated, but not sure if it is relevant.

Comment: You might have an infinite loop there... maybe that's the hangup.   Where are you getting "window_id"?

Comment: @pcalkins Sorry it was the redundant code I was using while developing. The loop finishes properly, and the console is waiting for my input.

Comment: without that your remaining window handles array is left unchanged.  You might want to build an array of handles specific to the additional tabs.  You can safely use driver.close on those.  For the last opened tab/window it'll be safer to quit the driver, which should both close the browser window and dispose of the driver.  Right now the loop looks a little messy with the if/then and try/catch conditions all triggering .close() methods and always switching to the first element in the array.  Remember, too, that the order of the handles is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your installed Java version on your Macbook. It seems like when you have version 8 installed it is not optimized/compiled for the M1 Macbook, making it insanely slow.

I fixed the issue by deleting the installed Java version, then downloading temurin11 (java11) by following this tutorial: https://collabnix.com/how-to-setup-java-on-apple-mac-m1-pro-in-2-minutes/. There doesn't seem to be a compiled version of java8 for the m1 macbook which is optimized. Java 11 is the earliest version which is.

After that my tests worked just as fast as they did with my previous intel Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

if you used chromedrivermanager.install() or some other way and installed wrong driver, you can download correct one and specify the path like this

```
chrome_options.binary_location = "./chromedriver"
```

After that, it worked like I opened it normal.