# How can I stop Selenium Firefox from opening a URL in a new window? (instead of a tab)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I use Selenium on Python and tried to use Firefox driver (as [Chrome is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778093/selenium-with-chrome-is-extremely-slow-if-i-navigate-manually?noredirect=1#comment130279438_73778093)), but for some reasons Firefox driver always opens a new URL in a separate window, not a tab. Here is my driver initialization:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) 
options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
options.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-GB')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
```

And then it is just open each URL with `window.open`.

```
for url in page_lists:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{0}", "_blank");'.format(url))
```

This opens each URL in a new tab in Chrome driver, but how can I make Firefox driver do the same thing?

I tried adding these preferences according to [this documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries), but none of them worked. In fact, the browser does not have a check-tick on the "open in a new tab" on the preferences page.

```
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0)
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_external", 3)
```

profile.set_preference("browser.block.target_new_window", True)

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of selenium, you can use the following to open a new tab in the same window:

```py
driver.switch_to.new_window("tab")
```

Then you would use the following to open a URL in that tab:

```py
driver.get("URL")
```

Comment: Isn't this just open a new tab?

Comment: Then you would use ``driver.get("URL")`` to open the URL in that tab.

Comment: So is there no way to open in a new tab using Javascript's `window.open`? It's faster.

Comment: There's `driver.execute_script("window.open('');")` if for some reason you don't like the built-in method.